# Rails 3 problem with second, third ActiveRecord methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Last week this worked but now, for some reason I can only use Model.first. Model.second and Model.third, etc no longer work.

Did something change in Rails? I keep getting a NoMethodError.

Comment: `Model.second` was added in Rails 4.1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model.second` never worked, I don't think. `second` and `third` work on arrays, however. Maybe you used something along the lines of `User.all.third` the first time.